# Why is my parser.next scanner picking up on a parenthesis and number instead of the string that comes before i despite having a delimiter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

The document I'm scanning says "enter(10);add;(45.76)" on a single line. It's supposed to read over the parenthesis and semicolons and just get the numbers and strings, as well as read the word "enter" before running the code. It manages to read enter correctly and the first number, but after that when scanning for "equation" it instead grabs **45.67)** with the parenthesis. If i remove the (45.67) and leave just **add;** it works and grabs the add. I'm not sure what's going on wrong here. Any help would be appreciated, as well as any advice on how to get this program to scan the next line in the file if there was another one.

```js
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CPLParser {

 public double parseScript(String inputFile) throws CPLException{
  File file = new File(inputFile);
  try (Scanner Filereader = new Scanner(file)){
   String line = Filereader.nextLine();
   Scanner parser = new Scanner(line);
   parser.useDelimiter("\\(|\\)\\;");
   String enter = parser.next();
   double number = 0;
   String equation = " ";
   double numberTwo = 0;
   double total = 0;

   if (!enter.equals("enter")){
    throw new InvalidProgramStartException("");
   }

   while (parser.hasNext()) {
    if (parser.hasNextDouble()){
     number = parser.nextDouble();
    }
    if (parser.hasNext()){
     equation = parser.next();
    }
    if (parser.hasNextDouble()){
     numberTwo = parser.nextDouble();
    }
    if (equation == "add") {
     double thistotal = number + numberTwo;
     total += thistotal;
    }
   }
   System.out.println(equation);




  } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
   System.out.println("Could not find the file");
  } catch (InputMismatchException e) {

  }

  return 0;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in your sample code:

Firstly in java you can not compare string with == you should use Equals method to check equality.
Secondly operation should be done after reading entire line,
also there were blank chars were read by scanner we need to handle that

Please have look into below working code and verify the output.

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException; 
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        try {
            Scanner parser = new Scanner("enter(10);add;(45.76)");
            parser.useDelimiter("\\(|\\)|\\;");
            String enter = parser.next();
                System.out.println("enter "+enter);
            double number = 0;
            String equation = " ";
            double numberTwo = 0;
            double total = 0;

            if (!enter.equals("enter")){
                // new InvalidProgramStartException("");
                System.out.println("InvalidProgramStartException");
            }

            while (parser.hasNext()) {
                if (parser.hasNextDouble()){
                    number = parser.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("number "+ number);
                }
                if (parser.hasNext()){
                    String text= parser.next();
                    // only set equation if its not blank
                    if ("".equals(text))
                    { System.out.println("equation is Blank "+ equation +"...");}
                    else
                    {equation = text;
                    System.out.println("Setting equation "+ equation);}
                }
                if (parser.hasNextDouble()){
                    numberTwo = parser.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("numberTwo "+ numberTwo);
                }

            }

            if (equation.equals("add")) {
                    double thistotal = number + numberTwo;
                    System.out.println("thistotal "+ thistotal);
                    System.out.println("total "+ total);
                    total += thistotal;
                    System.out.println("total "+ total);
                }
            System.out.println(equation);





        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very interesting and helpful, yet for some reason, my scanner is still grabbing "47.56)" as the .nextLine() and I am not sure why. It's not making much sense. Though your code seems to work just fine.